# Making a project to receive and input data

Tags: python-3.x

newbie python programmer here. I want to create a program which will input a value from an array in a field of a website, receive the information provided by the website, and put it in a spreadsheet. I think it's doable but I don't know how to approach it. Can anyone help me out and tell me how should I start and what modules I should know about. I'm still an absolute beginner so there'll be many things that I won't know about So I would very much appreciate if the explanations were a bit simple. TIA :D

Comment: Please show what you have tried.I would recommend you to learn python first. Try google it.

Comment: Well. If I got everything, you're going to need a module for the array, something for web automation, and something to make a spreadsheet. So, looks like you've got a need for numpy, selenium, and possibly pandas?